# Cordova inAppBrowser works in iOS but not in Android (ionic)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I working in an ionic app where I want to open all my links with the in-app Browser. I'm working in El Capitan OSX - Cordova 5.1.1

When I see the ionic app in an iPad (using ionic view) I can open the link I put in my button but the same doesn't work with a Samsung Galaxy Tab.

This is the button code:

```
<button class="button" ng-click = 'openBrowser("http://google.com")'> Click me :)</button>
```

this the relevant part of the controller

```
//in App Browser inAppBrowser
    var options = {
      location: 'yes',
      clearcache: 'yes',
      toolbarposition: 'top', 
      toolbar: 'yes'
    };

    $scope.openBrowser = function(externalSiteUrl) {
     $window.alert("we are into inAppBrowser!");
      $cordovaInAppBrowser.open(externalSiteUrl, '_blank', options)
      .then(function(event) {
         // success
         $window.alert("Success"); 
      })

      .catch(function(event) {
         // error
         $window.alert("nothing!"); 
      });
    };

    //end in App Browser inAppBrowser
```

In Android I can see the alert "We are into inAppBrowser" but nothing happens.